# Blank screen after changing ACL in ParseClass

Tags: android, parse-platform

I wanted to add a specefic ACL to one of my Parse classes by defining it in the constructor the following way:

```
public class Activity extends ParseObject {
    private ParseACL acl;

    public Activity() {
        acl = new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        setACL(acl);
    }

}
```

But ever since I added those lines to the constructor, my app is a blank screen.

Here is my Parse definition:

```
 public  void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    ParseObject.registerSubclass(MyClass.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Category.class);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Activity.class);
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(Constants.APP_ID)
            .clientKey(Constants.CLIENT_KEY)
            .server(Constants.SERVER_URL)
            .enableLocalDataStore()
            .build()
    );

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL,true);
}
```

Does anyone know where this could come from ?